# Как получить последнее сообщение от пользователя Vk_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Нужно получить последнее сообщение, которое написал пользователь в вк. Прибегал к методу messages.getHistory, но почему-то отсылается последнее сообщение от бота, а не от пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `api.messages.get`:

```
session = vk.Session(token)
api = vk.API(session)

messages = api.messages.get(count=1)
last = messages['items'][0]['id']
```

Comment: Зашел в документацию messages.get, а там пишет: "Данный метод устарел и может быть отключён через некоторое время, пожалуйста, избегайте его использования.". Есть ли какой-то другой способ?